# REST GET endpoints returning different models based on user role

Tags: rest, api-design, restful-architecture

I'm currently dealing few endpoints returning different kinds of models based on permissions:

For example, our business object is getting converted to either an object of type `Model` or `AdvancedModel`.

```
public class Model
{
  public int Property1 {get; set;}
}

public class AdvancedModel : Model
{
  public int Property2 {get; set;}
}

public IActionResult Get()
{    
   (...)
   return User.IsAdmin 
      ? Mapper.Map<AdvancedModel>(Client);
      : Mapper.Map<Model>(Client);
}
```

Initially this was built so everyone could retrieve client's basic details (name...) BUT only admin could get access to "sensitive" information (preferred payment info, billing contacts).

This makes makes our API harder to understand as we need to identity what fields are returned based on the permission level... This works well but I'm afraid it will become funky as we scale up (new roles, endpoints).

We have considered introducing new endpoints but it will add a bunch of them to our already packed API.

```
/api/v1/admin/clients/1234
vs
/api/v1/clients/1234
```

I was just wondering what's the best practice to handle that kind of scenario?

Thx

Comment: Nothing prevents you from returning user specific data in responses. How you manage these internally is up to you or the framework you use. I.e. a Java/Spring (ecosystem) based solution might provide certain resource and resource assemblers classes which support you in only exposing properties the user has actually access too. A certain uri-design shouldn't be necessary IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found that it can become confusing for a REST api to return different things depending on who's accessing the resource. This becomes even more complicated when you're accepting changes with `PUT`.

I don't think this a general advice, because different situations might require different solutions, but in your specific case I think it makes more sense to just have different resources.

It's fine for a 'piece of data' to be represented on more than 1 point in the API, however, another thing you could do is consider the following:

```
/clients/1234 <- could contain all the data
                 everyone may see.

/clients/1234/billing <- contains only the
                         billing information
                         admins can see.
```

I think this also plays well into the idea that it's good to avoid inheritance and use composition instead. You don't need a `Model` and an `AdvancedModel`. You need both `Model` and a `Billing` model.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what was posted by [Evert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80911/evert), you could use different `media types` for different responses. The media-type is also a good place to **support versions in your api**.

```
//fullrecord is only returned to admins
GET -H"accept=application/vnd.yourcompany.fullrecord.v1+json" /clients/1234
//fullrecord can also only be set by users with admin role
PUT -H"content-type=application/vnd.yourcompany.fullrecord.v1+json" /clients/1234
```

For all others

```
//this will just return public info
GET -H"accept=application/vnd.yourcompany.v1+json" /clients/1234
```

For the client

```
//this will just return infos for logged in the client
GET -H"accept=application/vnd.yourcompany.client.v1+json" /clients/1234
```

This would mean that a user with role admin can explicitly request a certain view by setting the appropriate accept header. It also leads to a cleaner URI design.